# How to select a single radio button at a time in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-radio-button to implement a flatlist with radio button as shown in the image.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But i am unable to select a single radio button at a time in flatlist.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image, LayoutAnimation, UIManager, Platform } from 'react-native';
import RadioButton from 'react-native-radio-button';
import PHARMACY from './api/mockPharmacyList';
import { Colors, Fonts } from '../../styles';

interface IState {
    selected: number;
    selectedIndex: number;
    data: any;
    expanded: boolean;
    checked: boolean;
}


export class TransferToPharmacy extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: PHARMACY,
            selected: 0,
            selectedIndex: 0,
            expanded: true,
            checked: false,
        };
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
        this.renderSeparator = this.renderSeparator.bind(this);
        this._keyExtractor = this._keyExtractor.bind(this);
        this.changeLayout = this.changeLayout.bind(this);
        this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        }
    }

    changeLayout = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.setState({ expanded: false });
    }

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            value: 0,
        };
    }
    onPress(value) {
        this.setState({ selected: value });
    }

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    onCheck = () => {
        const { checked } = this.state;
        if (checked === true) {
            this.setState({ checked: false  });
        } else {
            this.setState({ checked: true  });
        }
    }

    renderItem(data) {
        const { item } = data;
        return (
                <View style={styles.itemBlock}>

              <TouchableOpacity   >

                    <View style={styles.arrowIconStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.pharmacyText}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <RadioButton
                            innerColor={Colors.darkBlue}
                            outerColor={Colors.lightGray}
                            animation={'bounceIn'}
                            isSelected={this.state.selectedIndex === 0}
                            onPress={this.onPress}
                        />
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>{item.key1}</Text>

                 <View style={{ height: this.state.expanded === true ?  90 : 0, overflow: 'hidden' }}>

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 5, padding: 10 }}>
                             <Image style={[styles.itemImage, { width: 15, height: 15, margin: 1 }]} source={require('./images/map_pic_icon.png')} />
                             <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.location}</Text>
                         </View>

                         <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 5, padding: 10 }}>
                            <Image style={[styles.itemImage, { width: 15, height: 15, margin: 1 }]} source={require('./images/phone_icon.png')} />
                             <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.phone}</Text>
                         </View>

                     </View>
                </View>
        );
    }

    renderSeparator() {
        return <View style={styles.separator} />;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Transfer to Pharmacy</Text>

                <View style={styles.childViewStyle}>
                    <FlatList
                        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.black,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginLeft: 20
    },
    childViewStyle: {
        margin: 20,
    },
    itemBlock: {
        paddingVertical: 15,
    },
    itemImage: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 25,
        margin: 10
    },
    itemText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: Colors.darkySkyBlue
    },
    itemName: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.black,
    },
    separator: {
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: Colors.lightGray,
    },
    pharmacyText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: Fonts.bold,
        color: Colors.black

    },
    radioStyle: {
        marginTop: 10,
        marginRight: 50,
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    arrowIconStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 10
        // flex: 1
    }
});
```

with this code i am not able to select the radio button

Please let me know where it is going wrong as i am unable to select  radio button in the flatlist separately.

i have changed onPress() like this

```
onPress( index) {
        this.setState({  selected: index, });
    }
```

and in renderItem method i have changed it like this

```
const { item, index } = data;
 <RadioButton
                            innerColor={Colors.darkBlue}
                            outerColor={Colors.lightGray}
                            animation={'bounceIn'}
                            isSelected={this.state.selected === index}
                            onPress={() => this.onPress(index)}
                        />
```

Now the output is like this

[image]

Now the first radio button is selected but when i tried to select other radio buttons they are not getting selected.

Here is my mock data file which is used for Flatlist.

```
export const PHARMACY = [
    {
        key: 0,
        name: 'Plaza Pharmacy',
        type: 'Urgent Care Center - 4.01 mi',
        location: '3417 Gaston Avenue, Suite 195\n Dallas, TX 75202',
        phone: '469.764.7100',

    },

    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'Courtyard Pharmacy',
        type: 'Urgent Care Center - 4.09 mi',
        location: '5236 West University Drive, Suite 1900\n MCKINNEY, TX 75071',
        phone: '969.264.7190',
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        name: 'Outptaient Pharmacy at the Cancer Center',
        type: 'Urgent Care Center - 4.66 mi',
        location: '3800 Gaylord Parkway, Ste 110\n FRISCO, TX 75034',
        phone: '890.664.8130',
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        name: 'Carrolton Pharmacy',
        type: 'Urgent Care Center - 4.08 mi',
        location: '5236 West University Drive, Suite 1900\n MCKINNEY, TX 75071',
        phone: '969.264.7190',
    },
    {
        key: 4,
        name: 'Garland Pharmacy',
        type: 'Urgent Care Center - 22.11 mi',
        location: '3417 Gaston Avenue, Suite 195\n Dallas, TX 75202',
        phone: '469.764.7100',
    },
];
```

I am exporting this const PHARMACY and importing it in my class and set this to a state variable "data".

Comment: have checked when you press the radio button which value is logged? the reason is the value index value is not being passed to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do something like this in `renderItem`

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
 .....
<RadioButton
  innerColor={Colors.darkBlue}
  outerColor={Colors.lightGray}
  animation={'bounceIn'}
  isSelected={this.state.selectedIndex === index}
  onPress={() => {this.onPress(index)}}
/>
}
```

and replace `onPress` with

```
onPress = (index) => {
   this.setState({ selectedIndex: index });
 }
```

and update `FlatList` with `extraData props` as `FlatList` needs to be re-rendered as

```
<FlatList
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   data={this.state.data}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
   extraData={this.state}
 />
```

You can refer in snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/HkzA9cCSB)

Comment: There is change in the on press could you verify it

Comment: your solution is working but the problem is my code here in <Flatlist data={this.state.data} />

Comment: I didn't get you could you elaborate in more detail.

Comment: I have used mock data for FlatList and kept it in a separate tsx file and export the const PHARMACY in my current class and assigned that PHARMACY to a state variable "data" and in my FlatList I am inplace of data I am simply calling data={this.state.data}  These are the lines of code    import PHARMACY from './api/mockPharmacyList';     this.state= {data: PHARMACY} ,  <FlatList data={this.state.data} />

Comment: I don't see any issue with this as you are supplying data to flatlist. What issue did you get with this?

Comment: could you show the mock data or could you make snack for this so that it will be easy to debug.

Comment: Hi i have added mock data in the question and updated it please check it once.

Comment: @Rama I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I have checked the snack , For me also it is working if i put the data array in Flatlist itself but the problem comes when i call the state variable in place of data like this <FlatList data={this.state.data}

Comment: @Rama I got it. Please see the updated one along with the snack.

Comment: Thank You so much Kamal Pandey, finally it is working

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the index of the current item like so:

`const { item, index } = data;`

After you get the index of the current item you can then check if the current radio button is selected or not and for changing the radio button you need to pass the value of the current index to the `onPress` function.

```
<RadioButton
  innerColor={Colors.darkBlue}
  outerColor={Colors.lightGray}
  animation={'bounceIn'}
  isSelected={this.state.selected === index}
  onPress={() => this.onPress(index)}
/>
```

Comment: with this first radio button in the flatlist is checked but  iam unable to select the other radio buttons

Comment: I was comparing `selectedIndex` with `index` which I changed to `selected`

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of output in my question,  please check it once